# PowerShell check for service existance on remote machine - reliably?

Tags: powershell, service

I'm currently trying to check a bunch of remote machines for the existence of certain services. Currently that process is pretty slow (as in > 1 hour for a few hundred machines) which isn't much of a problem but also unreliable (which is a problem).

Some of those machines might be blocking access, turned off or might in some other way limit access to query for the services.

The current approach is to check with [`Get-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service?view=powershell-5.1) and as it has proven to be unreliable to also check with [`Get-WmiObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1) as well as [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-5.1).

The problem is that they don't support timeouts so if a server is just unresponsive it will take quite a bit of time to get a response and because all three options might work or not depending on the machine there really isn't an option to only run one. As one of them might succeed where the others failed I need to check the results of all three calls.

Would anyone have an idea on how to do a sort of preflight check to figure out which command might work or if there is a different approach to checking for the existence of a service that might be more reliable?

The current approach looks akin to this (simplified):

```
$error.Clear()
$serviceExists = $false
$server = "localhost"
$serviceQuery = Get-Service -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Name WinRM -ComputerName $server
$wmiQuery = Get-WmiObject   -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Class     Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'WinRM'" -ComputerName $server
$cimQuery = Get-CimInstance -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ClassName Win32_Service -Filter "Name = 'WinRM'" -ComputerName $server

if ($error.Count -ge 1) {
    Write-Output "An error occurred while check for the service existence on $server"
}

if (
    ($serviceQuery | Where Name -eq 'WinRM') -ne $null -or
    ($wmiQuery | Where Name -eq 'WinRM') -ne $null -or
    ($cimQuery | Where Name -eq 'WinRM') -ne $null
) {
    $serviceExists = $true
}
```

As far as I can tell it might be that `Get-Service` internally uses (the same approach as) `Get-WmiObject` and `Get-CimInstance` but I wasn't able to find documentation on that. The machine currently use PowerShell 5.x, PowerShell remoteing might or might not be configured on the servers that are being queried for the service existence.

Edit: `Get-Service` is unreliable because it might not indicate that there was an issue and just return `$null` without indicating that there actually was a problem. Also while it might fail one of the other options might still work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "unreliable"? Also, starting with PowerShell v6 the `Get-Service` cmdlet doesn't have a parameter `-ComputerName` anymore, so you'd have to use `Invoke-Command` for running it remotely.

Comment: See the edit; it's unreliable because it's not a definite return and at least `Get-Service`might not indicate that it did have an issue and what kind of issue it was. Thanks for pointing out that version 6 will change the behavior, I changed the documentation links to version 5.1. Checking e.g. port availability by running [`Test-NetConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=win10-ps) would be nice but there doesn't seem to be a documentation on what ports are required for those cmdlets to work.

Comment: [IBTD](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/832017/service-overview-and-network-port-requirements-for-windows). `Invoke-Command` and `Get-CimInstance` use WinRM (ports 5985 and 5986), `Get-WmiObject` uses WMI (i.e. DCOM/RPC, ports 135 and 49152-65535).